# Creating an input select in an editable form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

From the `App` component, I bring `status = paid` to the `Todo` component, then to the`EditForm` component. The contents of `this.props.status = 10` attempts to display in`input select`. In select, I put `value = {this.props.status}`. Select should display `paid`. It displays `unpaid`. Status value is 10, but I want display 
 instead of 10 I want to display 'paid'

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xsl5mf

```
  class EditForm extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <select defaultValue ={this.props.status} onChange={(e) => this.props.handleChangeStatus(e)}>
              <option value="0">Unpaid</option>
              <option value="10">paid</option>
              <option value="20">free</option>
            </select>
        )
  }
}

class Todo extends Component {

  state = {
    status: ''
  }

  handleChangeStatus = (evt) => {
    this.setState({
      status: evt.target.value
    })
  }


  componentDidMount = () => {
    const { todo } = this.props;

    this.setState({
      status: todo.status
    })
  }

  render() {

    return (

        <EditForm
            handleChangeStatus={this.handleChangeStatus}
            status={this.props.status}
          />
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {

      todos: [
        {
          status: 10 //paid
        }
      ]
    };
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.todos
              .map((todo, index) =>
                <Todo
                  key={index}
                  index={index}
                  todo={todo}
                />
              )
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Todo` : you call `EditForm` with `status={this.props.status}`, `this.props.status` is `undefined` and should be `this.state.status`

In `EditForm` : use `value` instead of `defaultValue` and the values of the options are not the same as the status, you'd get `paid` in the props as `status` but the `option`'s value is `20`, you'll need to handle that, for the snippet below i chnged it to `paid` :

```js
class EditForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <select value ={this.props.status} onChange={(e) => this.props.handleChangeStatus(e)}>
          <option value="0">Unpaid</option>
          <option value="10">paid</option>
          <option value="20">free</option>
        </select>
    )
  }
}

class Todo extends React.Component {

  state = {
    status: ''
  }

  handleChangeStatus = (evt) => {
    this.setState({
      status: evt.target.value
    })
  }


  componentDidMount = () => {
    const { todo } = this.props;

    this.setState({
      status: todo.status
    })
  }

  render() {

    return (
      
        <EditForm
            handleChangeStatus={this.handleChangeStatus}
            status={this.state.status}
          />
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {

      todos: [
        {
          status: '10'
        }
      ]
    };
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.todos
              .map((todo, index) =>
                <Todo
                  key={index}
                  index={index}
                  todo={todo}
                />
              )
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: And what to do if I have instead of status: 'paid', status: 10, but want to display in select as `paid`?

Comment: yes, put `10` as status instead of `paid` , check the edit

Comment: I understand. 10 has to be string? not number?

Comment: it can be a number

Answer (score 0):

In your component Todo you are passing the this.props.status which is undefined since such a prop does not exist.

In your Todo componetn when it is mounted you set the status to be `todo.status`

However here it receives this.props.status whereas you should be passing this.props.todo.status since componentDidMount is uncessary here and it won't actually reflect the status since it will trigger it after the `render()` method. You could use componentDidMount but it is deprecated 
so you can do what you are doing inside the constructor.

If you still want to keep the values as integer then you will have to map them to the strings.

```
  const prices = {
    paid: 20,
    unpaid: 10,
    free: 0
   }
```

```js
 <EditForm
    handleChangeStatus={this.handleChangeStatus}
    status={this.props.status}
  />
```

On the other hand your values do not match the value that's being sent to the component. It should be as following since if you define value='10' and has the string of paid it won't know which value is the default value. Your event handler will update the status to be the price in this case.

```
 <select defaultValue={this.props.status} onChange={(e) => this.props.handleChangeStatus(e)}>
          <option value="unpaid">unpaid</option>
          <option value="paid">paid</option>
          <option value="free">free</option>
 </select>
```

Take a look at this example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qjn31r)

Comment: And what to do if I have instead of status: 'paid', status: 10, but want to display in select as paid? Value must have 0, 10, 20. Display in select unpaid, paid, free. Status=10. convert to unpaid and display unpaid

Comment: You can map it through an object `const prices = { paid: 20, unpaid: 10, free : 5}; const price = prices[this.state.status]`

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `EditForm` should be like below

```
    <EditForm
    handleChangeStatus={this.handleChangeStatus}
    status={this.state.status}
    />
```

And before passing it `defaultValue` do conversion and map paid to `10`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a couple things wrong:

- `this.props.status` inside **Editform** doesn't exist.
- The value inside the option elements is incorrect, they should match the string that you are passing into the defaultValue.

  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import { render } from 'react-dom';
  import Hello from './Hello';
  import './style.css';

  class EditForm extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
         this.props.handleChangeStatus(e)}>
            Unpaid
            paid
            free
          
      )
    }
  }

  class Todo extends Component {

  state = {
      status: ''
    }

  handleChangeStatus = (evt) => {
      this.setState({
        status: evt.target.value
      })
    }

  render() {
      console.log(this.state)
      return (

  ```
      <EditForm
          handleChangeStatus={this.handleChangeStatus}
          status={this.props.todo.status}
        />
  )
  ```

  }
  }

  class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();

  ```
  this.state = {

    todos: [
      {
        status: 'paid'
      }
    ]
  };
  ```

  }

  render() {
      return (

    {
                this.state.todos
                  .map((todo, index) =>
                    
                  )
              }

  );
    }
  }
  render(, document.getElementById('root'));